# How many and what letters are in a word

Tags: arrays, char, cpu-word

I have to make a program in c# that takes all letters from a word and displays how many and what letters were there.

Example:

Input = Hi there!

Output = 2×h; 1xi; 1xt;...

Any tips how should I do this with the use of arrays?

Comment: Simply google for *"count letters in X"* where X is the language you have failed to mention.

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are using but...

Do the follow:

1. Ask the user to input the word
2. take the word and count the length
3. Count the letters and display them

**NOTE:**  General questions get general answer ;)